# How make a 6x6 board rotate using LEGO technic parts?

Tags: technic, mechanical

Are there any common patterns for making a 6x6 (or bigger) LEGO board have a ability to rotate using technic with gears and such? Has to be without the help of the existing 2x2 lego part that rotates, its not big enough.

Seen from above:

[image]

Comment: Would you like the 6x6 plate to rotate on some kind of axis, or would it suffice to have some kind of coaster system that you rotate by holding the 6x6 plate and turning it yourself?

Comment: A simple, brutal solution if you want motorisation would be a round plate that has an axle hole, attached to an axle attached to the motor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a large gear ([3649](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3649)) with connector pegs ([970607](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=970607-1)) attached like this: 
[image: Gear with connector pegs]

Then you can attach the 6x6 plate on top.

Comment: For smaller assemblies, a 2x2 round brick is probably more than you'll ever need as it has a cross hole in the middle

Comment: @Joubarc: I was thinking of that too, but the OP said that "existing 2x2 lego part is not big enough", so I didn't suggest that.

Comment: I thought he meant the turntable, but you're probably right

Answer (score 7):

There's actually a specialized part to accomplish this task. Take a look at the [Technic Turntable](http://brickset.com/parts/4211381) (2855):

[image: 2855]

This part can be used to create sturdy rotating platforms that can be controlled by gears. It consists of two parts (2855 and 2856) that snap together to allow for smooth rotation about the center. Here's an example from the classic [Mobile Crane](http://peeron.com/inv/sets/8460-1) set:

[image: mobile crane base]

With the crane boom mounted:

[image: mobile crane complete]

Note that this turntable is out of production, so it may be easier to find the new studless version, though it will obviously be a little more difficult to attach regular bricks to this one. The studless version is part 48452 and 48168. Here's what is looks like with the two halves snapped together:

[image: studless technic turntable]

Comment: There are several different turntables, the one linked is somewhat old and might be hard to find. Bricklink has a category list: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=40

Comment: That's a great point. I assumed from the question that it would be helpful to use gears to directly control the turntable, but if that isn't important than many other turntables could do nicely. I updated the answer to include the newer studless Technic turntable as that should be easier to find, allows direct drive, and isn't in the turntable category that you linked to.

Comment: That's annoying. The Technic Turntables are in the generic Technic list: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=4&catString=36&catType=P (there are small ones that also allow geared drive)